# JsRender - call a helper within helper

Tags: jsrender

Is it possible to call a helper within helper declaration?

I define two helpers: `someFunctionA` and `someFunctionB`. I would like to use `someFunctionB` and inside that call `someFunctionA`

I've tried calling `someFunctionA()` and `this.someFunctionA()`.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<span>{{:~someFunctionB(123)}}<span>
```

**JS**

```
$.views.helpers({
    someFunctionA: function(value)
    {
        return value++;
    },
    someFunctionB: function(value)
    {
        new_value = someFunctionA(value);

        return "the value is: " + value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
new_value = this.ctxPrm("someFunctionA")(value);
```

See [www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@ctxprm](https://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@ctxprm)

Or you can simply do

```
functionA() {
    return value++;
}
functionB() {
    new_value = functionA(value);
    return "the value is: " + value;
}
...
$.views.helpers({
    someFunctionA: functionA,
    someFunctionB: functionB
});
```

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for your help! I've tried your suggestion but I get this.ctxPrm is not a function

Comment: I inserted a test sample above, which works for me. Renders "the value is 124".
The this.ctxPrm() call is within a helper declaration, whose this pointer is the toplevel view. 

Are you using the latest jsrender.js / jsviews.js ? Otherwise, can you create a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: I was using pre V1.0 commit counter: 64, now I've tried 1.0.2 and it's working. thank you very much